# Remove gateway for private network on Server with 2 ethernet ports - Why

Tags: centos, wide-area-network, nic

I have a server with 2 ethernet ports, use one port (eth0) for the private LAN, and a public IP from ISP is on second port (eth1).

I have it working, but I'd like to know the reason why I have to remove the gateway from the private network in order for both private LAN and public network to both work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Typically there can only be at most one default gateway.

A default gateway is a generic route which is used for any IP address not specified elsewhere. As a route it has a form of 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0.

You have defined the IP address range of your LAN, and for the rest of the Internet you should take the default gateway.

If you define another default gateway on a LAN you are sending Internet packets to a no-exit alley, instead of routing them through the motorway.

Another consideration: If you only have a simple LAN with no Internet access you don't even need a default gateway.